# Starting MySQL database server: mysqldinstall: invalid user `mysql'

Tags: debian, mysql, raspberry-pi

i have a problem with mysql on my Raspberry Pi running `Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux`.

This is error I have when I run `sudo service mysql start`

```
Starting MySQL database server: mysqldinstall: invalid user `mysql'
```

I haven't found answer anywhere, so I'm asking here.

mysql version: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (armv7l) using readline 6.2`

`etc/passwd` file:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh list:x:38:38:Mailing List
Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System
(admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
sshd:x:101:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
ntp:x:102:104::/home/ntp:/bin/false
statd:x:103:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/bin/false
messagebus:x:104:106::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false usbmux:x:105:46:usbmux
daemon,,,:/home/usbmux:/bin/false lightdm:x:106:109:Light Display
Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false mysql:x:107:112:MySQL
Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false ftp:x:108:113:ftp
daemon,,,:/srv/ftp:/bin/false
wp:x:1001:1004::/media/usb/www/wordpress:/bin/bash
ntop:x:109:114::/var/lib/ntop:/bin/false
git:x:1002:1005:,,,:/home/git:/usr/bin/git-shell`

`/var/log/mysql.err` and `/var/log/mysql.log` empty.

grep 'mysql' /var/log/syslog: (I solved another problem before)

`Apr 14 13:55:11 raspberrypi mysqld: 150414 13:55:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
Apr 14 13:55:11 raspberrypi mysqld:
Apr 14 13:55:11 raspberrypi mysqld: 150414 13:55:11 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Apr 14 13:55:12 raspberrypi mysqld: 150414 13:55:12  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Apr 14 13:55:14 raspberrypi mysqld: 150414 13:55:14  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 6669110
Apr 14 13:55:14 raspberrypi mysqld: 150414 13:55:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Apr 14 13:55:14 raspberrypi mysqld:
Apr 14 13:55:15 raspberrypi mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Apr 14 21:03:00 raspberrypi /etc/init.d/mysql[3611]: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
Apr 14 21:03:56 raspberrypi /etc/init.d/mysql[3706]: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
Apr 14 21:04:36 raspberrypi /etc/init.d/mysql[2269]: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
Apr 14 21:08:02 raspberrypi /etc/init.d/mysql[2592]: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
Apr 14 21:10:51 raspberrypi /etc/init.d/mysql[2750]: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!`

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: Thanks for help, but still the same